# How is the high frequencies are found in the rise time of signal?

Tags: signal, oscilloscope, high-frequency

I have read an article from Tektronix on how oscilloscope probes affect your meausurment
here i read that:

> The consequence of a large capacitance value is severe because the front edge of the signal contains the high frequency content.(page 6)

[article](https://assets.testequity.com/te1/Documents/pdf/probes-affect-measurement-an.pdf)

Comment: next time, please take the instruction "enter link description here" serious and enter a link description.

Comment: This is probably the best explanation on the internet of how waveform relates to Fourier components https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY

Comment: @Markus sure, i just did know how.Thanks Martin. I am going to read that now